# Wordpress doesn't display posts matching 2 categories

Tags: php, wordpress

I have posts, matching 2 categories. Parent->Child1
Trying to get posts only from child1 category, but wordpress displays post only if it has 1 category.

Example:

Post 1. Categories: Parent, Child1

Post 2. Categories: Child1

I use

```
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 20, 'orderby' => 'date', 'post_type' => 'post', 'category' => $Child1_category_id );
$postslist = get_posts( $args );
```

But it returns only Post 2.
And i need to get Post 1 and Post 1.

What am i doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using this type of args:

If not work try use the 'parent' in the query_posts.